# PHP Text over image - Text doesnt show on the saved image

Tags: php, image

I have this code working which puts text over an image in PHP, however when I save the generated Image onto my computer only the image shows and the text doesn't.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
    $imgPath = 'template4.png';
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);

error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  

{
    $GT = $_POST['GT'];


    $Gamertag = preg_replace('/ /', "+", $GT);



    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.ea.com/uk/football/profile/{$Gamertag}/360");


    if ($content == false) {
        echo "Cant find this Gamertag";
        exit(); 
    }


    // Titles Won

    preg_match('#<div class="stat">
                Titles Won                <span>([0-9\.]*)<span class="sprite13 goalImage cup"></span></span>#', $content, $titleswon);
}


$string = $titleswon[1];
$fontSize = 3;
$x = 5;
$y = 5;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagepng($image);
?>
```

If I just set $string to $string = 'hello'; the word hello stays when saved, but because I am using preg_match to grab a value to print onto the image, When I save it the text doesn't show.

Any help, thanks.

Comment: so this is a regexp problem....

Comment: how do you save the image?

Comment: Just right click + save

Comment: what happens if you save it directly using imagepng($image, The path to save the file to.)

Comment: i'll put it as an awnser so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the image directly using:

```
imagepng($Image, The path to save the file to.)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, this is the regexp problem, not text-to-image problem.

first of all, you should check results of preg_match against boolean false, to see if the matching succeeded. 
replace any whitespace in the pattern with `\s+` or `\s*`
do at least var_dump to see the results of matching.

Comment: The text does show on the image though, so the preg_match must be working, its only when I save the image it doesnt show